# Weaker form of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm looking to formalize a weaker type of convergence than standard $o(\cdot)$ which requires the limit to be 0. My condition is stronger than $\lim\inf = 0$ which would be equivalent to $\not\in\Omega(\cdot)$. In particular, I want some succinct convergence condition connecting non-negative functions $f$ and $g$ (both of which are finite and monotonically non-decreasing in $x$), that is implied from $\int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^2}dx < \infty$, and $\int_{x_1}^\infty \frac{g(x)}{x^2}dx =\infty$ for some $x_1 \geq x_0$.

For example, clearly for any constant $c > 0$, $\lambda(\{x: f(x) < cg(x)\}) = \infty$. However, one could think about $f(x)$ being defined as $1$ for $2n \leq x \leq 2n+1$ for all integers $n$ and 0 elsewhere, and such an $f$ would satsify the condition without converging to $g$ in any sense of the word. Of course this $f$ isn't monotonically non-decreasing in $x$, however the condition in and of itself doesn't really imply convergence at all.

For example, a "nice" statement (if true) would be that for every constant $c > 0$,  $\lambda(\{x: f(x) \geq cg(x)\}) < \infty$. However, I'm not sure that is implied by the fact that $\int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^2}dx < \int_{x_1}^\infty \frac{g(x)}{x^2}dx =\infty$. If it is, could you please provide a proof (or hints)? For example, it would be sufficient if the integral for $\frac{g(x)}{x^2}$ over any set of infinite measure was infinite (again, I don't know if this is true or not, probably not). If the statement isn't true, what kind of conditions would $g$ need to satisfy to make it true (if there are any)?

Of course, in the general form, one would want to have the statement be as widely applicable as possible (e.g., it is better if we don't require $f$ or $g$ to be monotonically non-decreasing in $x$).

Comment: Now that I think about it, clearly the $\frac{1}{x^2}$ could likely be removed for the types of statements being made (unless the convergence statement requires a "with respect to" part)

Answer (score 0):

So obviously the $\frac{1}{x^2}$ can be folded into the $f$ and $g$ themselves.

And then the nice statement is a good one for $g$ as long as there exists some constant $k > 0$ such that $\mu(\{x \geq x_1: g(x) < k\})$ is finite. In that case, the weaker form of convergence could be that for all constant $c > 0$, $\mu(\{x >= x_1: f(x) \geq c g(x)\}) < \infty$. This is implied from $\int_{x_1}^\infty f(x) dx < \int_{x_1}^\infty g(x) dx = \infty$.

Otherwise, assume by contradiction there is some constant $c$ for which $A = \{x \geq x_1: f(x) \geq cg(x)\}$ has $\mu(A) = \infty$. But in that case $\int_{x_1}^\infty f(x) dx \geq \int_{A} f d\mu \geq c \int_{A} g d\mu = \infty$ where the last step follows from [Infinite Lebesgue integral over all infinite measure subsets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518758/infinite-lebesgue-integral-over-all-infinite-measure-subsets/) for $A$ with $\mu(A) = \infty$.

But then the problem with this is that the condition on $g$ requires that $g(x)$ can't converge to 0 which limits the applicability.